# open existing java project in eclipse

Tags: java

As one of our dev guy is on vacation, I got his task. The source code is in our svn repository and i got down the java project source. downloaded eclipse 3.3.2 sdk as that were his instruction.

How do I open an existing project in eclipse? Coming from MS world, i do not have the luxury of finding a .sln file.

Comment: Do you have the code checked out already, or do you need to work from scratch?

Answer (score 67):

1. File -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace
2. Browse for that directory.

Alternative: Check out the code in SVN to some folder

1. Create a new folder in windows
2. In eclipse File -> switchWorkspace -> newFolderName
3. close the welcome window in eclipse
4. In eclipse File -> Import -> Existing project into workspce-> select root dir -> browse and show the svn checkout folder

Comment: You would think that they would create an open an existing project already.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a simple Java project, You essentially create a new project and give the location of the existing code. The project wizard will tell you that it will use existing sources.

Also, Eclipse 3.3.2 is ancient history, you guys should really upgrade. This is like using Visual Studio 5.

Answer (score 2):

The typical pattern is to check out the root project folder (=the one containing a file called ".project") from SVN using eclipse's svn integration (SVN repository exploring perspective). The project is then recognized automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse does not have internal Subversion connectivity.  After you've downloaded and unzipped Eclipse, you have to install a Subversion plug-in.  Check with the other developers as to which Subversion plug-in you're using.  Subclipse is one Subversion plug-in.

After you've installed the Subversion plug-in, you have to give Eclipse the repository information in the SVN Repositories view of the SVN Repositories perspective.  One of the other developers should have that information.

Finally, you check out the project from Subversion, by left clicking on the Package Explorer, selecting New -> Project, and in the New Project wizard,left clicking on SVN -> Checkout projects from SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you just open klik file -> import -> General -> existing project into workspace -> browse file in your directory.

(I'am used Eclipse Mars)