# Opening java project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded as a zip the java project:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven

I'm not familiar with Eclipse. When I download this zip file and unzip to a folder in my desktop, how do I open the project in Eclipse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095996/open-existing-java-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

1 . Launch your eclipse

2 . Select `File->Import` from the menu bar

3 . Expand `General` and choose `Archive` file ( since you have a zip )

4 . Browse it from the downloaded location

Works ?

OR

Just unzip your eclipse project . Now you can use the same sequence of steps `File->Import` followed by `General` . Here pick `Existing Projects into Workspace` . Browse to your unzipped project .

**RE-EDIT - ANSWER**

I had a look at the project that you are trying to load . Its not an eclipse project . It is an `Netbeans` project . I was able to load it into `Netbeans` . So in other words do the following .

1 . Download `NetBeans` and install it on your system .[Netbeans Download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

2 . Import the project into `NetBeans` via `File -> Import Project -> From Zip` .

Comment: I tried various ways and keep getting " No projects are found to import"

Comment: @ConfusedDeer For it to be a eclipse project that can be loaded into eclipse there must be a .project file in the directory from where you are trying to browse . If this is not there then you wont be able to load . This .project file is not something which you create but would/should have been made available in the extracted zip . Is it there ?

Comment: Thanks I just realized this as well. Is there a way to tell what IDE a project was built in?

Comment: @ConfusedDeer well in general if there are files in the folder with prefix with nb then immediately Netbeans comes to mind . An eclipse project will have a .project file . These are just small hunches . Maybe there are better ways to determine .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do a few things

1. Read this [Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-ide-eclipse.html) on Maven and Eclipse
2. Install [Maven Integration (m2e)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)
3. [Import](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/) the File (archive) into your workspace

Comment: I tried various ways and keep getting " No projects are found to import"

Comment: Does it work when you follow your links' setup instructions (outside of eclipse)?

Comment: I wanted to utilize eclipse first, but looks like I'll have to follow those instructions first.

Comment: After you get it working on the command line, just do `mvn eclipse:eclipse` - then you can import it.